# Asp.Net Core WEB API error 404 calling method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-routing

I'm trying create an additional Get method on a web api but the return is 404 ( method not found ).

At my APIs before Core I was creating such methods like :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/MyNewMethodName")]
public object MyNewMethodName(string parameter1)
{}
```

And for call :

```
myURL/api/MyNewMethodName?parameter1=somestring
```

At my controller definition I have :

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/MyController")]
public class MyController : Controller
```

For the exactly some code I receive the 404 error.

What is wrong please ?

Comment: Does your controller has any prefix decorator attributes ?

Comment: At my controller I have : 

[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/MyController")]
public class MyController : Controller

Comment: Update the question with that please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your controller has a route defined. So for your action method, it will be the route prefix defined for the controller **+** the route pattern for the action method. That means, with your current code, it will work for the below request

```
yourBaseUrl/api/MyController/api/MyNewMethodName?parameter1=somestring
```

Here `api/MyController` part is from the route definition on the controller level and the `api/MyNewMethodName` part is from the action method level.

Fix the route prefix at controller or method level as needed. For instance if you want your action method to respond to `/api/MyNewMethodName?parameter1=somestring`. Just remove the `Route` decorator on the controller level.

```
[Produces("application/json")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/MyNewMethodName")]
    public object MyNewMethodName(string parameter1)
    {
        return "Sample dummy response : "+parameter1;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that, removing the controller level routing might break routes to other action methods in that controller. If you want to keep the existing routes as it is (with the controller level route attributes), You may update your action method level route pattern to start with a `/`

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/MyController")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/MyNewMethodName")]
    public object MyNewMethodName(string parameter1)
    {
        return "Some test"+parameter1;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("SecondMethod")]
    public object SecondMethod(string parameter1)
    {
        return "SecondMethod : "+parameter1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it's now ok with your first suggestion and ok too with your second suggestion. But in the second case, removing the Route docorator, the standard get methods are not being routed anymore.

Comment: @GCoe In that case put back the route prefix and update the desired actions to override the prefix with the tilde (`~`) i.e: `[Route("~/api/MyNewMethodName")]`. Reference [Routing to Controller Actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing) 
Reference [Routing in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing)

Comment: The route pattern starting with `/` will also work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

[HttpGet]

[Route("api/[controller]/MyNewMethodName")]

public object MyNewMethodName(string parameter1)
{

}

Try declaring the above format, this worked for me.